# Silverlight website inaccessible

Tags: silverlight

We have two different servers that are stored as virtual machines @ amazon 
One is a copy of the other (we did that after configuring the first).

The servers host a silverlight application.

The client can surf on site1 but not on site2

He uses IE9.

Please advise how at all should I look for a solution

Thanks!

Comment: What's not accessible about it? Is the server unreachable, the code untrusted, something else?

Comment: he sees a blank page
but he can right click it and see the silverlight settings.
I asked him to delete the storage and he did.
Did not work

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of others:

There are a lot of reasons for "white screen" for Silverlight applications .

Specifically my problem was that the xap file was blocked by the IT team on the client premises ...